# How to compare int.MaxValue in if condition C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind `TextBox` in ASP.NET with the maximum values that it can hold are `int.MaxValue`. The following code throws an error.

```
using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDelete", scon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox6.Text);
    scon.Open();
    if (TextBox6.Text != null && TextBox6.Text <= int.MaxValue)
    {
        int del = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (del == 0)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label2.Text = TextBox6.Text + " Record not found";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label2.Text = TextBox6.Text + " Deleted Successfully";
            LoadGV();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        Label2.Text = TextBox6.Text + " Enter a valid value";
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compare a string to an integer. Convert your textbox value to int and then compare it

Comment: It really helps to know what the error is. First though, you can't compare TextBox6.Text, which is a string, to an integer. Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text) <= int.MaxValue   is more what you are looking for. You'll have to ensure TextBox6 actually holds a number though. Any non-numeric character will blow that up.

Comment: @Turbulence facing an error with your suggestions  when it comes in if comparison _Value was either too large or too small for an Int32._

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick I want that when value exceed from an integer it goes to else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.Text` is of string type. You should convert to a `int` type for comparison.

Replce below line

```
if (TextBox6.Text != null && TextBox6.Text <= int.MaxValue)
```

with

```
bool validInput = false;
try {
    Int32.Parse(TextBox6.Text);
    validInput = true;
}
catch {
}
if (TextBox6.Text != null && validInput)
```

Please note that the `try` may throw exception as the string input is invalid. You may catch specific exception if required. You can refer to MSDN for possible exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It can't be length. It should the value in that textbox I suppose. int maxvalue is `2147483647`. So, as per your condition, I can  enter 2147483650 as well

Comment: The `inputValue <= int.MaxValue` clause is superfluous as it's always true.

Comment: @QadeerMangrio -  It wont because int maxvalue is `2147483647`. The answers are posted. You can use any of these.

Comment: Edited to remove `inputValue <= int.MaxValue` because if `Int32.Parse()` does not throw exception, it indicates the value can be convert to `int` type which must be <= `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: Why would you wrap int.parse in a try catch when there is int.tryparse? Does the same thing but is cleaner.

Comment: Well, you are right, it seems tafia's answer is better.

Answer (score 6):

Textbox.Text is a string, not an int. I guess you should just try converting it to an int before:

```
int val;
if (Int32.TryParse(TextBox6.Text, out val) && val <= int.MaxValue) {
 // your stuff ...
}
```

Note that you don't need to set the connection outside of the if block

Comment: To be accurate val <= int.MaxValue is preferable.

Comment: @tafia is it necessary to use out parameter here?

Comment: @Qadeer, this is required by the `TryParse` method ... The alternative is described in @Mango Wong post and is far more verbose.

Comment: Wouldn't `val <= int.MaxValue` always be true?

Comment: @Matthew, you're right, I've let it there for the example, in case he'd like to set any threshold